# Probabilistic Analysis of Algorithm in simple language?

Tags: algorithm, probability

Could anyone explain the Probabilistic Analysis of Algorithm in simple words?  Couldn't find much info in Wiki page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to determine the expected runtime of a comparison-based sort algorithm. Here's how you would approach this problem:

- Define a distribution over all possible inputs to the algorithm

  - For example, say that all N! permutations of ordering N distinct numbers are equally likely (1/N!)
- Determine the runtime for each possible input
- Compute the **expected** runtime by summing up over all possible inputs the probability of the input times the runtime for the input

  - That is, E[Runtime] = sum<sub>i=1,...,N!</sub>{ P(i) * Runtime(i) } = sum<sub>i=1,...,N!</sub>{ Runtime(i) } / N!

For example, if you do this with the quicksort algorithm (with naive choice of pivot), you will find that the **expected** runtime of quicksort is O(N log N) while the **worst-case** runtime is O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: lets say i want to determine the expected run time in case of a problem where we  find the maximum in an unsorted array.Here the worst,average and best case will be O(n). Using the expeceted run time formula.how do we find its o(n)?

Comment: @RahulKurup The following inequalities always hold: Best <= Expected <= Worst. Should be very intuitive why. So if Best = Worst = O(n), of course Expected is O(n).

Comment: Can we mathematically prove this? In the case of maximum                                                     E[Runtime] = sumi=1,...,N{ P(i) * Runtime(i) } = sumi=1,...,N{ Runtime(i) } / N     and run time of i is always n ..so n^2/n=n..is this proof correct?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great presentation which explains this in simplistic terms

http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/survey-Stellenbosch.pdf

IMHO, it boils down to  "Given an algorithm and "typical input" what would be the performance of a randomized algorithm"

where, typical input  really depends on for what purpose you are evaluating the algorithm, you can provide a uniform or a random distribution for input value and measure performance characteristics

Answer (score 0):

In simple language:

If you want to cook a steak, you'd know that the size of your steak will change the time needed on the grill for it to be ready. The raw steak is your input, the grill is your function (i.e. alg.) and the cooked one is your output.

Now, say that I ask you: "how much time does it take your grill to grill a steak on average?" how would you go about that?
Probabilistic Analysis suggests that all possible sizes of steaks could come your way.Therefore, this method produces **average running time** .This method will provide you a number that represents this situation, so you could perhaps compare different grills.
Hope that helps!

Comment: @Rahul Kurup - Hope this helps :)